# MySQL View with data out of two Tables

Tags: mysql

i need to create a view with data from two different tables.

i tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW `moviesdatastore`.`view_user_group` AS
SELECT user_name FROM tbl_spj_user, 
SELECT group_name FROM tbl_spj_group;
```

But this causes:

```
ERROR 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

Cant see where is the subquery.....

How can i create a view for data out of two different tables?
I need it for JAAS on my java web application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
CREATE VIEW `moviesdatastore`.`view_user_group` AS
(
  SELECT user_name AS name FROM tbl_spj_user
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT group_name AS name FROM tbl_spj_group;
)
```

Note that you won't know which entries come from groups and which come from users. If you need to differentiate on that, add another column to the view with the type, eg:

```
CREATE VIEW `moviesdatastore`.`view_user_group` AS
(
  SELECT user_name AS name, 'user' AS type FROM tbl_spj_user
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT group_name AS name, 'group' AS type FROM tbl_spj_group;
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can join the tables then join should be better then union

```
CREATE VIEW  `moviesdatastore`.`view_user_group` AS 
SELECT 
user_name 
FROM tbl_spj_user 
INNER JOIN tbl_spj_group ON tbl_spj_group.groupID=tbl_spj_user.groupID
```

Comment: its an M:N Relationshipt between user and group

Answer (score 1):

May be a join is what you want.

```
CREATE VIEW `moviesdatastore`.`view_user_group` AS
SELECT A.user_name, B.group_name 
FROM tbl_spj_user A
LEFT JOIN tbl_spj_group B ON A.group_id = B.id;
```

Comment: its an M:N Relationshipt between user and group